# Laggspike every few seconds

Tags: cpu, performance

Since a few weeks, I have this issue where there's a slowdown which effects my entire system. The lagg only starts after I've started a particular game (I have seen this occurring after playing Minecraft or Portal 2, but Tomb Raider didn't seem to be affected), and then quit it. When I do this, the lagg starts even when I watch a YouTube video or play a GIF. This also occurs in Windows, but Fortnite doesn't seem to have trouble with it. I monitored my CPU, and when the spikes have started you can see the CPU usage skyrocket:
[image: CPU usage spikes]
[image: even more spikes]
I haven't monitored it under Windows, but I think that yields a simular result. It's all very strange, and it's really annoying.

I tried to find a program that consumed a lot of CPU when it occurred, but the only thing I found was compiz, and killing compiz didn't really help.

Specs:

- Intel Core i5 6400
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, graphics driver 384.111 under Linux
- Samsung 750 EVO 250GB SSD
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, is going to be replaced by 18.04 in a few days
- Windows 10 on an extra HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was most likely a driver issue. After a reinstall and installing another driver it worked again.